# c# invokemember click not working

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, css

I would like to press automatically "Vans, Trucks & Plant" button.
After pressing it should come another table with expanded meniu,
but invokemember click not working (in all other cases on the same page working well)...

Here is part of the page code:

```
<div class="category-scroll" data-category-active="2551">
<ul class="category-list-content" style="transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.57, 0.1, 1); transition-duration: 0ms; transform: translate(0px, 0px) translateZ(0px);">
<li class="border-b is-parent" data-category-children="true" data-category-id="9312" data-category-url="vans-trucks-plant" data-category-name="Vans, Trucks & Plant">
<span class="category-name">
<span class="category-list-control is-parent"></span>
Vans, Trucks & Plant
</span>
</li></ul>
<div class="iScrollVerticalScrollbar iScrollLoneScrollbar" style="position: absolute; z-index: 9999; width: 7px; bottom: 2px; top: 2px; right: 1px; overflow: hidden;">
</div>
```

Here is how I do, but no results:

```
foreach (HtmlElement el in webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("li"))
{
if (el.InnerText == " Vans, Trucks & Plant  ")
  el.InvokeMember("click");
}
```

Any suggestions? 
Maybe I need to invoke some script?

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (HtmlElement el in webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("li"))
{
if (el.InnerText.Contains("Vans, Trucks & Plant"))
  el.InvokeMember("click");
}
```

Comment: ah, I see. Sorry, but I can reach by debuging el.InvokeMember("click"); so contains is not a solution...